# Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_proxy_wstunnel

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to use the Websocket Proxy in Apache, but keeps reporting non existent module.
$ sudo a2enmod mod_proxy_wstunnel
ERROR: Module mod_proxy_wstunnel does not exist!

This should be available from 2.4.5!
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Is this an Ubuntu version problem?
How can I install this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with proxy_wstunnel

$ sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel

Comment: I think it worked, but I'm not using Apache anymore. Thank you any way.

Comment: out of curiosity what websock server are you using now and why?

Comment: NGINX. Why... a lot of people seems to agree that it's better. For me, at least it was easier.